# Need help in dynamically created select option tag using jquery[For Jquery mobile]

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-select

I'm creating a select Options dynamically under a  using jquery. I have set the first item as selected using selected attribute. But i couldn't able to see the first item in select list. if i select second or third item the text is displaying in select tag.[image][image][image]

EDIT : and one more thing i need to say,here am using jquery mobile framework.

Can any one help me.

here is my HTML script :

```
<select id="HRselectList"></select>
```

JS :

```
for(var x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
{
  $('#HRselectList').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",x).text(x));
  if(x==0)
  {
    $('#HRselectList option').attr("selected","selected");
  }
}
```

Comment: how could this not work? It worked for me. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GTyZ3/

Comment: Hi, Actually am using jquery mobile framework. if i remove jquery mobile framework its working fine. how can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code but wasn't seeing the problem. I do however think that I know where the problem comes from. Try this instead...

```
var HRselectList = $('#HRselectList'),
    x = 0;

for (; x < 6; x++) {
    HRselectList.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", x).text(x));
}

HRselectList.find('option').eq(0).attr("selected", "selected");​
```

... and let me know if it's working.

**Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ggmHe/ .**

Comment: Hi thank u for quick reply. its working well if i didn't use jquery mobile framework. i need the script work on jquery mobile. any ideas ?

Comment: Not really ;) I'll investigate.

Answer (score -1):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/GTyZ3/1/

If you are working on jquery mobile, I think simpler approach might go all the way. This is a bit immature approach, but I hope it will work.